# Cool Way to Show Matrix Output in Mathematica Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion

This is not really a question, but I thought I would share what I just learned as some folks might find it helpful when entering questions involving matrices in StackExchange. Try:

```
Clear[a, b, c, d]
s1 = SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> a, {2, 3} -> b, {5, 2} -> c, {6, 7} -> d}]
```

When I want to discuss my matrix output on StackExchange, I can use TeXForm:

```
TeXForm[Normal[s1]]
```

I take the output from my notebook and paste it between two double dollar signs in StackExchange and it produces this output:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 a & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & b & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & c & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & d \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Since "this is not really a question", it doesn't really belong here. Even if you *did* phrase it as a question and answer, it probably better belongs on Meta, anyway.

Comment: Firstly, you can write it in Q&A form with can not only make this post more fit in the site, and can also attract further or better solutions. Secondly, lets move it to meta :)

Comment: It's a shame that have migrated it to a site where latex is not supported, the demonstration no longer works!

Comment: @mikado One could post an image of how it looks on the main site, I suppose.